# Why I get empty object from constructor PHP?

Tags: php

I have two users classes:

```
class Elastic
{

    protected $elastic;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->elastic = new \Elastica\Client();
    }

}
```

And my second class extends first:

```
class Map extends Elastic
{

    private $mapping;

    function __construct($elasticaType)
    {
        var_dump($this->elastic); die();
    }
}
```

But I get an empty object from `$this->elastic`. What is wrong with what I'm doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've omitted the call to the parent constructor which contains behavior that you rely on.

```
class Map extends Elastic
{

    private $mapping;

    function __construct($elasticaType)
    {
        parent::__construct();
        var_dump($this->elastic); die();
    }
}
```

In PHP (and many other OO languages) a subclass may choose to call the function it's overriding.